# If new value exists in previous dates then count duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an automated table "Customers_Status" where if new customers registered with a service, they will be flagged as 1 otherwise 0. However, i want to check for the new customers if the serial number they used to activate their service had been used before for other customers, and how many times has it been used.

`Customers_Status` Table:

```
ID      Date_Key      New_Customer      Serial_No
1       20200920           1             A12345
2       20200920           1             A123456
3       20200920           1             A1234567
4       20200920           1             A12345678
5       20200920           1             A123456789
```

i tried to do a self-join, it takes forever to run and i'm not quiet sure if it correct:

```
select 
t1.ID, t1.Date_Key, count(t1.New_Customer), t1.Serial_No, count(t2.Serial_No) as Serial_No_Usage_Count
from Customers_Status t1
left join (select * from Customers_Status t2 where Date_Key between 20200101 and 20200901) t2 on t1.Serial_No = t2.Serial_No
where t1.New_Customer = 1
and t1.Date_KEY = 20200920
group by t1.ID, t1.Date_Key, t1.Serial_No
```

The output should be something like

```
ID      Date_Key      New_Customer      Serial_No            Serial_No_Used_Before       Serial_No_usage_count
1       20200920           1              A12345                   No                             0
2       20200920           1              A123456                  Yes                            12
3       20200920           1              A1234567                 Yes                            3
4       20200920           1              A12345678                No                             0
5       20200920           1              A123456789               Yes                            47
```

Comment: What is the data type of column DATE_KEY? Is is VARCHAR2 or is it DATE?

Comment: @Abra DATE_KEY is Number(30)

Comment: I don't understand your requirements completely. Tell me how 2nd and 3rd rows are 'Yes' for the column Serial_No_Used_Before. And how are you calculating Serial_No_usage_count ? Please provide complete sample data that represents your scenario. And explain the logic. Based on your version there may be a better solution also. So, please tell us what is your Oracle DB version. If you don't know how to find out then just run SELECT BANNER FROM V$VERSION

Comment: @Ranagal let me put it in example: I go and buy 1 software licenses and then I shared that license with you. Now the the company who issued the license wants to check if anyone is giving away their license. I am the company in this example. As for the "used_before" column, I don't know how to create it so just added it as a desired output if anyone knows how to.. and using oracle 12c

Comment: You may *additionaly profit* from storing the date column in data type `DATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated as per update of the question and new example.**

I would use modern `outer apply` (it's the same as lateral(+)) here:

```sql
select
   t1.*,
   lat.*
from customer_status t1
     outer apply(
       select 
              case when count(*)>0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end Serial_No_Used_Before
             ,count(*) Serial_No_usage_count
             ,listagg(ID, ',')
                 within group(order by ID) IDs_with_the_same_serial
       from customer_status t2
       where t2.ID != t1.ID
         and t2.Serial_No = t1.Serial_No
         and t2.Date_Key between 20200101 and 20200901
    ) lat
where t1.New_Customer = 1
and t1.Date_KEY = 20200920
order by id;
```

Full test case with sample data:

```sql
with customer_status(ID, Date_Key, New_Customer, Serial_No) as (
select 1, 20200920, 1, 'A12345'     from dual union all
select 2, 20200920, 1, 'A123456'    from dual union all
select 3, 20200920, 1, 'A1234567'   from dual union all
select 4, 20200920, 1, 'A12345678'  from dual union all
select 5, 20200920, 1, 'A123456789' from dual union all
select 6, 20200122, 0, 'A12345678'  from dual union all
select 7, 20200222, 1, 'A123456789' from dual 
)
select
   t1.*,
   lat.*
from customer_status t1
     outer apply(
       select 
              case when count(*)>0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end Serial_No_Used_Before
             ,count(*) Serial_No_usage_count
             ,listagg(ID, ',')
                 within group(order by ID) IDs_with_the_same_serial
       from customer_status t2
       where t2.ID != t1.ID
         and t2.Serial_No = t1.Serial_No
         and t2.Date_Key between 20200101 and 20200901
    ) lat
where t1.New_Customer = 1
and t1.Date_KEY = 20200920
order by id;
```

Results:

```
        ID   DATE_KEY NEW_CUSTOMER SERIAL_NO  SER SERIAL_NO_USAGE_COUNT IDS_WITH_THE_SAME_SERIAL
---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- --- --------------------- --------------------------------------------------
         1   20200920            1 A12345     No                      0
         2   20200920            1 A123456    No                      0
         3   20200920            1 A1234567   No                      0
         4   20200920            1 A12345678  Yes                     1 6
         5   20200920            1 A123456789 Yes                     1 7
```

As you can see it also allows you to easily get IDs of the customers with the same `serial_no`.

One of the cons of this solution is that Oracle optimizer can *decorrelate* the query from `outer apply` and use hash join outer, so usually it performs better.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select cs.*,
       (case when new_customer = 1 and
                  min(date_key) over (partition by Serial_No) < date_key
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end)
from customer_status cs;
```

If you want to filter for just new customers, use a subquery:

```
select cs.*
from (select cs.*,
             (case when new_customer = 1 and
                        min(date_key) over (partition by Serial_No) < date_key
                   then 'Yes' else 'No'
              end) as flag
      from customer_status cs
     ) cs
where new_customer = 1;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff thanks for posting your answer. However, it doesn't return the flag and there's constant conditions on new_customer and date_key (can't change them because I'm also joining 5 other tables).. please read my post again and ask if it isn't clear let me know. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't return the flag"?  The flag is an additional column in the result set.

Comment: Yes. It's not completely clear what you want. Please see my comments for your orginal question and provide the answer in your original post.

Comment: I mean I ran your code and the "flag" column doesn't not appear in the output

Comment: @user2803287 . . . You are doing something wrong.  The `select cs.*` in the outer query is selecting all columns in the subquery, and that includes the additional flag column.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information how many time a serial number was reused use simple a `SUM` analytic function of the column `NEW_CUSTOMER` partition by the `SERIAL_NO`

You want the information only in rows with `NEW_CUSTOMER = 1` so suppress it with a `CASE` statement

The `ID` of the new customers with the same `SERIAL_NO` assigned can be obtained with `LISTAGG` fuction used in analytical form. Again you filter onyl keys from *new customer* rows *and* from the rows with duplicated *serial no* assignment.

Example for sample data - with commented results

```
    ID DATE_KEY   NEW_CUSTOMER SERIAL_
```

---

```
     1 2020-09-20            1 A12345   -- OK first assignment
     1 2020-09-21            0 A12345 
     2 2020-09-22            1 A12345   -- first illegal reuse 
     2 2020-09-23            0 A12345 
     3 2020-09-24            1 A123456  -- OK
     3 2020-09-25            0 A123456
     4 2020-09-26            1 A12345   -- 2nd illegal reuse
     4 2020-09-27            0 A12345
```

Note that I'm using `DATE` format to store the date  value - which is recommended.

Query

```
with tab2 as (
select 
  ID, DATE_KEY, NEW_CUSTOMER, SERIAL_NO,
  case when NEW_CUSTOMER = 1 then 
      sum(NEW_CUSTOMER) over (partition by SERIAL_NO order by DATE_KEY) - 1
  end as SER_NO_IDX
from tab)
select  
  ID, DATE_KEY, NEW_CUSTOMER, SERIAL_NO, SER_NO_IDX,
  case when SER_NO_IDX > 0 then
     LISTAGG(case when NEW_CUSTOMER = 1 and SER_NO_IDX > 0 then id end,',') within group (order by DATE_KEY) over (partition by serial_no) 
  end as dup_id_lst
from tab2
order by 1,2;

        ID DATE_KEY   NEW_CUSTOMER SERIAL_ SER_NO_IDX DUP_ID_LST
---------- ---------- ------------ ------- ---------- ----------
         1 2020-09-20            1 A12345           0           
         1 2020-09-21            0 A12345                       
         2 2020-09-22            1 A12345           1 2,4       
         2 2020-09-23            0 A12345                       
         3 2020-09-24            1 A123456          0           
         3 2020-09-25            0 A123456                      
         4 2020-09-26            1 A12345           2 2,4       
         4 2020-09-27            0 A12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that is worth executing on your actual data for fast results:

```
select ids id, dt_ky date_keys, new_cust new_customer, Serial_No, Serial_No_Used_Before, Serial_No_Usage_Count 
from
(
   select t.*, to_date(date_key, 'yyyymmdd') dt from tab t
)
match_recognize
(
    partition by serial_no
    order by dt
    measures final count (b.*) as Serial_No_Usage_Count,
             decode(classifier(),'B','Yes','No') as Serial_No_Used_Before,
             new_customer as new_cust,  id as ids, date_key as dt_ky
    pattern  ( a b*)
    define   b as new_customer = 1
)
where new_cust = 1 and dt_ky = 20200920;
```